# Swagger scan only annotated resources

Tags: java, maven, annotations, swagger, openapi

is there a way that swagger will only scan classes and fields that are annotated with @ApiModel and @ApiModelProperty ?

I am using the Maven Swagger Plugin and the problem is that it scans the complete models. The models contain fields that are used only for internal processing, some that are only used for our xml api and some that are only used for the json api.

I want swagger to only scan the fields for the json api. Therefore I only want to annotate the json fields.

My only solution now is to annotate every field and mark the one I don't need with "hidden".

Any idea how to achieve that easier ?

Comment: split them up into packages. E.g: `models.internal`, `models.xml` and `models.json`. Finally let Swagger only scan the ones from `models.json`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to checkout the swagger core project and change the code. In the ModelResolver class there is a line of code where it tries to grab the "ApiModelProperty" Annotation from the current model. There you have to make a null check and only execute the next lines if the annotation object is NOT null.

Only 1 line of code :

```
ApiModelProperty mp = member.getAnnotation(ApiModelProperty.class);
if(mp != null) { // custom modifcation
    // around 100 lines of code ...
}
```